# Hash output of CryptoStream

Tags: c#, .net, hash, cryptography

I'm using:

```
cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

and want its hash. If I use:

```
hash.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
```

it will (presumably) hash the input, not the encrypted buffer.

So how do I hash the **output** buffer?

Comment: Almost the same question as the one I linked to, but as you were not explicitly asking for a stream, so I guess that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions have an internal state. You don't need simultaneous access to an input buffer to create the hash over the data; you may as well use a stream.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725507/calculate-hash-when-writing-to-stream) explains how to calculate a hash using a stream (note the similarities of the question). Also note that the question probably contains the most complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the _question_ there. I did see it but was looking at the answer there which doesn't help me. Now I see that the question itself mentions "chaining" Streams and feeding the output of one write stream to the other. I'll have to check that out. Looks good...

Comment: ...On the other hand - I'm still left with a question because the OP there is just writing once, while I'm writing many times - will the hash be of the whole stream or only of the last buffer write?

Comment: The stream would not be of much use if it only works for one write... Why not try and write the stream to file (as in that example), then you can always compare the hashes using a command line utility or simple GUI application/explorer extension to create hashes over binary files.

Comment: Did you run into additional problems, ispiro, or did something not work?