# Encrypt and hash what has been encrypted in one go

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, hash

I'm trying to encrypt a file (using AES 128-bit block size, CBC mode, PKCS7 padding) and generate a hash (SHA1) of the encrypted file but all in one go.

It's trivial to encrypt the file to a MemoryStream and then calculate the hash for it, but doing so seems pretty inefficient specially if source files to be encrypted could be potentially quite large (a few GBs).

My idea would be to read the source file chunk by chunk (with a fixed chunk size), encrypt the chunk & pass the encrypted chunk to the hash algorithm, but it is my understanding that encrypting every chunk standalone won't produce the same result than encrypting the whole file (I may be completely wrong).

For now, I can't get around the CryptoStream to get what has just been encrypted by it and then pass that data to a hash algorithm implementation (eg. SHA1Managed.TransformBlock).

Just to clarify, I want to calculate the hash of the final encrypted file, not the source. And I'm using .NET Standard 2.1.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate hash when writing to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725507/calculate-hash-when-writing-to-stream)

Comment: Yes it does, and works as expected, thank you!